# ¿Como filtrar por dia de la semana? en sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, django, backend, sqlalchemy

Tengo la siguiente base de datos en sql alchemy

```
class Experiments(Base):
   __tablename__ = "experiments"

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
   operador = Column(String)
   experimento = Column(String)
   alturaInicial = Column(Integer)
   paraminiciales = Column(Boolean)
   tiempoinicial = Column(Integer)
   umbralinicial = Column(Integer)
   material = Column(String)
   floculante = Column(String, nullable=True)
   concentracion = Column(Float, nullable=True)
   unidadConcentracion = Column(String, nullable=True)
   dosis = Column(Float, nullable=True)
   unidadDosis = Column(String, nullable=True)
   densidad = Column(Float, nullable=True)
   unidadDensidad = Column(String, nullable=True)
   ph = Column(Float, nullable=True)
   comentarios = Column(String, nullable=True)
   expInit = Column(Boolean)
   nombre_inst = Column(String)
   limiteSuperior = Column(Integer)
   IT_id = Column(String)
```

En "nombre_inst" se guarda la fecha y hora del experimento como una string.
Quiero filtrar esta base de datos segun dia de la semana, pero he probado de todo y he preguntado
a chatGPT pero no se como seguir.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento.